# How can image effects be applied to text (TextObject) in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I'd like to apply image effects like blurring, wiping and masking to text displayed in my Corona SDK app.  If the text to be displayed were static, I could store it in an image file.  A DisplayObject based on that image could be instantiated using `display.newImage()` and the effects applied by setting the object's `fill` property. (This is explained in the [section on image effects](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/effects.html) in the Corona Developer Guide to Graphics/Audio/Animation.)

However, the text I need to display changes every time the user launches the app.  It is based on a combination of phrases selected at random from a list and is displayed in a font and font size that depend on user preferences.  So the image asset approach cannot be used in this case.

Is there a way to apply image effects to TextObjects created using `display.newText()`?  These objects have no `fill` property, so it's not clear that these effects can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that TextObjects have no `fill` property and, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to apply image effects directly to them. I tried various image effects and even simpler fills like gradients.  No dice.

I realized, however, that TextObjects (like all DisplayObjects) can be inserted into the GroupObject of a SnapshotObject which **does** have a `fill` property. From the [Snapshots section](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/snapshot.html) of the Graphics dev guide:

> Snapshots inherit all functionality of rectangles. For example, all 2.5D effects are available to snapshot objects.

By inserting only the TextObject into the snapshot and applying image effects to the latter, you effectively apply the effects to the text.

This code snippet demonstrates this solution.  The effect I'm implementing makes the text, which is initially hidden, appear through a circular keyhole with a blurry edge. (The transition is done in three phases to preserve the blurry region between the inner and outer radius.)

```
local textString = "This is some string generated at Runtime."
local textObj = display.newText({
    text = textString,
    font = myFavoriteFont,
    fontSize = myFavoriteFontSize})
textObj:setFillColor( 0 )

local snapshot = display.newSnapshot( textObj.contentWidth, textObj.contentHeight )
snapshot.group:insert( textObj )

snapshot.fill.effect = "filter.vignetteMask"
snapshot.fill.effect.innerRadius = 0.01 
snapshot.fill.effect.outerRadius = 0 

sceneGroup:insert( snapshot )

local totalTimeForTextToAppear = 2000 -- duration of transition in milliseconds
local timeStep = totalTimeForTextToAppear / 3 -- duration of each phase of the transition
transition.to( snapshot.fill.effect, {delay = 0, time = timeStep , innerRadius=0.5})
transition.to( snapshot.fill.effect, {delay = timeStep, time = timeStep, innerRadius=1} )
transition.to( snapshot.fill.effect, {delay = timeStep, time = timeStep, outerRadius=.5} )
transition.to( snapshot.fill.effect, {delay = 2 * timeStep, time = timeStep, outerRadius=.99} )
```

(When using this approach, all the usual "gotchas" regarding snapshots on Android devices apply.  These are [discussed here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSnapshot.html#android).)

This is the solution I found to my question.  I would love to see any other workarounds I may have missed.